# .Net Core MVC site not showing in MS Teams Web

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iframe, microsoft-teams

I have a fully working ASP.NET Core application that outside of an Iframe works perfectly well. However, I want to show this site within MS Teams. It works in the desktop application but not in the Teams Web Application.

Initially it would not load but adding:

```
services.AddAntiforgery(x => x.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true);
```

Now it loads but when I try to login the site authenticates but then does not redirect.  At the point of

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")
```

the site just reloads the login page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please provide us code snippets or repro steps , so that we can try out from our end?

Comment: Are you still blocked on this? Could you please share repro steps?

Comment: Thanks @Wajeed-MSFT for getting back to me.  I have since discovered the issue.  The authentication cookie must be set to SameSite=None to work inside Teams/iFrame.  I am not willing to take this risk.

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered that for my authentication cookie to work I must set the cookie as Samesite=None which is a security risk I am not willing to take.  Will just have to wait for Teams to come up with an alternative solution.